´´´UWPLaunchActivatedEventArgs.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol´´´ is never fulfilled
I want to launch a WinUI app via URIfrom the explorer and pass some parameters.
  protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.UWPLaunchActivatedEventArgs.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
        {
          e.UWPLaunchActivatedEventArgs.Arguments...

Unfortunately, despite URI launch working, the parameters are always empty and ActivationKind is still always set to 'Launch' when initiating via this URI:
myapp://?variable=value

I could really use some help with figuring out what I am missing here.

I tested it according to the official documentation and did not reproduce your behavior. Please try again according to the official instructions.

@JunjieZhu-MSFT I followed the documentation as far as I could but it doesn't seem to translate entirely to WinUI as 'OnActivated' doesn't exist in the new namespaces. I was suggested to use 'OnLaunched' instead, but the resulting behaviour is not the same as in UWP.

To avoid confusion; this is my application baseclass: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.application?view=windows-app-sdk-1.6

so, is it a WinUI3 project?

@JunjieZhu-MSFT Yes, I adjusted the tags to make it more clear.

The Arguments and UWPLaunchActivatedEventArgs properties are not supported in Windows App SDK apps.

Check the docs. UWPLaunchActivatedEventArgs is not supported in Windows App SDK. Instead you should be able to use Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() here.
For example:
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    string[] commandLineArgs = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

    Window = new MainWindow();
    Window.Activate();  
}


You can use Windows.ApplicationModel.AppInstance.GetActivatedEventArgs method and check if the Kind propery of IActivatedEventArgs object is Protocol or check if the object is ProtocolActivatedEventArgs. Then you can retrive the URI from the Uri property.
protected override void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    var e = Windows.ApplicationModel.AppInstance.GetActivatedEventArgs();
    if (e is Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ProtocolActivatedEventArgs p)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(p.Uri);
    }
    ...
}

